# I'm stuck on an assignment on Coursera. My output is correct but it still gives me a "mismatch" error. Please, can anyone help me out?

Tags: python

[My solution screenshot][1]

Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

largest = None

smallest = None

while True:

num = input("Enter a number:")

if num == "done":

```
break
```

try:

```
no=int(num)
```

except:

```
print("Invalid input")
```

if largest is None or no > largest:

```
largest = no
```

if smallest is None or no < smallest:

```
smallest = no
```

print("Maximum is", largest)

print("Minimum is", smallest)

My output:

Invalid input

Maximum is 10

Minimum is 2

← Mismatch

Desired Output:

Invalid input

Maximum is 10

Minimum is 2

---

As you can see my output is same but it still gives me error.
Help me anyone.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6wCE.png

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question (and pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)). There are [many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), why images of code are not a good idea. Most important reason: we can't copy the code from an image to our environments to test and improve it, so you make it more difficult to help you.

Comment: If I were to take a guess, print() adds a newline after each line by default. Try replacing the last line with print("Minimum is", smallest, end='')

Comment: **READ [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**

Answer (score 0):

1. In Python, break statement doesn't  require semicolon. Remove semicolon from break statement
2. Modify your code in below mentioned way, so that no need to check largest and smallest value for invalid input.

```
    largest = None
    smallest = None
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input("Enter the Integer")) 
            if num == "done":
                break
            if largest is None or num  > largest:
                largest = num 
            if smallest is None or num  < smallest:
                smallest = num 
        except:
            print("Invalid Input")
        
    print("Maximum is ", largest)
    print("Minimum is ", smallest)
```